# download excel file using htmlunit

Tags: file, download, htmlunit, window.location

I am trying to download xls file from a website using Htmlunit. When I click the link to download the file, I get a javascript confirm box.

I tried multiple options but not able to find the slution:

```
        ConfirmHandler okHandler = new ConfirmHandler(){              

            @Override
            public boolean handleConfirm(Page arg0, String arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        };
        webClient.setConfirmHandler(okHandler);
```

Also tried with

```
        final String page = currentPage.getElementById("downloadExcel").click().getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
        String buttonJavaScript = "window.location='...........'";
        ScriptResult result = page.executeJavaScript(buttonJavaScript);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
```

It would be really helpful if some one can suggest the solution for this.

Comment: Please post your complete case with URL, so others can reproduce the issue.

Comment: For example consider this url :
http://nrldc.org/WBS/injsch.aspx?date=25-02-2013

Here when click on All file is getting downloaded directly, but in my case I'm getting download window using window.location and I don't know how to handle this thing using htmlunit.